# How to set datasource in datatables.net on meteor Collection?

Tags: datatables, meteor

How can I set datasource in [datatables](http://datatables.net) with Meteor Collection?

Answer (score 1):

With Meteor its a bit different to C#/.NET. I'm not sure datatables explicitly takes a datasource from an array/an actual data variable. But it is possible to make a table from a minimongo query such as `People.find()`

You have your table which you're going to convert to a datatable. Make a basic table that loops with `{{#each}}` for each 'row/document'

```
<template name="data">
    <table id="datatable">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#each person}}
          <tr>
              <td>{{name}}</td>
              <td>{{address}}</td>
          </tr>
        {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

Then you attach data to this with a template helper that connects to your database:

```
 Template.data.person = function() {
     return People.find()  //Return the data containing name/addresses of people
 }
```

Finally something to convert the plain ordinary table to a datatable

```
 Template.data.rendered = function() {
     $('#datatable').dataTable()
 }
```

Comment: A data table is actually the main focus of an example Meteor project that I use to teach the basics of Meteor. It's on Github: https://github.com/primigenus/meteor-bedenktijdje - very similar code to Akshat's answer but without needing the datatables library.

Comment: @Rahul thats quite a nice project, im not fluent in dutch so your students can ask questions in real time and it pops up on the screen? Thats really cool

Comment: nah it's just a collection-backed list of people that you can resort and vote on, with voting limited by logged in state.

Comment: @Rahul even better! It sounds very interactive

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i get this error: Exception from Deps afterFlush function: TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null. Thank you in advance for your reply.